# Position text on top and centered on image in merge

Tags: android

I want to position a text centered horizontally and the image appear below the text with top margin 12 dp. how can i achieve this in a merge.xml file. Here's my code. IT contain a text and an image the image but i guess it's a wrong doing

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/item_image"

    android:layout_width="253dp"

    android:layout_height="240dp"

    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:scaleType="fitXY"

    android:src="@drawable/one_louisrossi" />

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="312dp"

    android:layout_height="295dp"

    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/eight" >

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/title"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fourty_eight"

        android:gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:text="xxxxxx"

        android:textColor="@color/yellow_green"

        android:textSize="@dimen/eighteen"

        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hiiii how r u ???  is that code works fine for u ???

Answer (score 3):

here is the xml file :

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Android"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/android" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: hey sophia i got the way to do this by using merge xml